# AKTabBarController missing issue

Tags: ios

I have an old IOS (objective C) project and it has used a library called AKTabBarController for the UI design. Currently this library is removed and when installing ‘pods’, it gets failed.

https://libraries.io/github/alikaragoz/AKTabBarController

I tried to download library files from a available source and linked those files manually. But still i’m getting that library related issues.

Can someone explain me what to do when a library is removed from the source.

Comment: Have you removed pods from the project?

Comment: @Rajeshkumar R I cloned the project from SVN and no pods were there when I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode. In your `Podfile`. Find the line `pod 'AKTabBarController'`, remove and save.

Comment: removing the line from the pod file will make pod installation successful. But the project won’t build because of the missing library

Comment: You should rebuild the project using another library because `AKTabBarController` is already discontinued for so long. When a library is discontinued, you need to find a different library.

Comment: This is used in the UI view and replacing the library without even looking at the UI is not practical I guess. I have no way to build and start the application. Basically, no way to replace it. Is there any other option?

Comment: If you really need to use that library, you can download and add the library to your project manually and remove  it from podfile.

Comment: I tried to do that. I found following locations. https://github.com/danielebogo/AKTabBarController
https://github.com/soundcloud/AKTabBarController 
But both seems to different from the original one. In my code, there are methods used which are not in a downloaded file. 

Can you help me to find the original library? I couldn’t find one

Comment: This is one of the downsides of using third party library. You need to be able to understand their code and when you want to make changes to meet your requirements. If you can't modify it, your only solution, unfortunately, would be to use another library.